# Python to Exe when your script uses batch file

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I have a script that uses a batch file, it makes batch file work by code. I try to make this script exe. I used auto py to exe and Pyinstaller. However I couldn't convert batch file to exe. My exe opens but doesn't work because of the lack of batch file. What I need to do to handle the batch file?

Comment: do you really need batch ? Can't you run it directly in Python using `subprocess` ?

Comment: did you check PyInstaller documentation which shows how to add extra data/files to project ? It will not add batch automatically to your exe (self-extracting ZIP file with extension .exe)

Comment: @furas I use subprocess

Comment: see PyInstaller doc: [Using Spec Files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) and [Adding Files to the Bundle](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle)